# Sum identical elements of an array based on their indicies

Tags: python, numpy

How would be elegant solution for summing all 2's from an array based on their indices?
I have this array `x = [2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 2]`

Then I found their positions with

```
y = where(isclose(x,2))
```

and get another array like this `y = (array([ 0,  1,  2,  4,  5,  6,  7, 10, 12, 13, 16])`

So how I can use with numpy to calculate sum of elements in  `x` based on indices in `y`.

Comment: what do you mean based on index `y`? Can you show the expected output for your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a simple [*indexing*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to get the corresponding items then use `np.sum`:

```
>>> np.sum(x[np.where(x==2)[0]]) 
22
```

Also note that you don't need `alclose` within `np.where` you can just use `x=2`.And as said in comment this is not the proper way to doing this task if this is the only problem.

Comment: Why the hard way? You can just count the number of elements and multiply by 2.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yeah this is not the proper way but maybe this is a simple picture of another problem or an example so I just suggested a way based on OP's request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `np.where` for this - an array of booleans, like the one returned by `np.isclose` or the various comparison operators, works as an index to another array (provided the sizes match). This means you get all of the 2's with:

```
>>> x[np.isclose(x, 2)]
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

And sum them directly:

```
>>> x[np.isclose(x, 2)].sum()
22
```

Answer (score 0):

If x contains only non-negative ints, you could sum the occurrences of each value with

```
total = np.bincount(x, weights=x)
# array([  0.,   0.,  22.,  18.])
```

The value of `total[2]` is 22 since there are 11 two's in `x`.
The value of `total[3]` is 18 since there are 3 three's in `x`.